# How to do what if analysis with report builder?

Tags: reporting-services, user-input, session-state, ssrs-2012

I'm having an Inventory cube with a dimension of "DimForecast". Related report is created by SSRS report builder and published to sharepoint.

End user wants to have what-if analysis so that they could **edit Forecast Value directly from user interface** (currently, ssrs report) and see how it will influence inventory stock.

Also, once their browser's **session is expired** (e.g. refresh webpage), all data will be **converted back to original ones**, which are pulled from Data Warehouse to cube.

Is there any possible work around for this functionality? "Power view" can do similar job but it's only available in Excel. However, for this case we have to use report builder, which is designed neither to user-interaction nor to session-based processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible input in the scenario you describe is a parameter e.g. "Forecast Value".  You would need to code SSRS expressions to accept the "Forecast Value" parameter and use it in SSRS Expressions to derive the returned data on the report.

A default value of 0 for the "Forecast Value" parameter could be used to effectively "reset" the data back to the original values.

It seems to be stating the obvious, but SSRS in SharePoint seems a really poor choice for a "what if analysis" requirement.

Comment: Yes, SSRS is not designed for this... IS there any other approaches with sharepoint for "what if analysis"

Comment: "forecast value" is imported from an excel file to SQL server with SSIS. It's a series of values instead of just one.

Comment: I would just publish an Excel file to SharePoint.